# Angular server side rendering: How to eliminate imports when "isBrowser = false"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, server-side-rendering

One of the components has this imports:

```
import * as  mapBoxGlClient from 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';
```

All builds works. 
But when I'm running node:

```
node main.server.bundle.js
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'hardwareConcurrency' of undefined
```

After investigation, I realized that mapbox requires window.navigator, browse etc.  All thing that can't be used in server

So my question is there any way to skip import, or any other idea will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the import (import are parsed and resolved before the code is run) but the code that uses stuff from that. As far as I know, there is no way to conditionally import things but you can conditionally execute code whether you are in browser environment or not.

Comment: I'm not showing this component if 'isBrowser=false'. I think the problem is in mapbox, I think this code running when mapBoxGlClient instance is created.